# Как автоматически обновлять курс валют в django-currencies?

Tags: python, linux, django

Я использую django-currencies для перевода цены по курсу валют на шаблонах. Для того чтобы обновить курс валют нужно вводить команду:

```
python manage.py updatecurrencies
```

Я настроил celery для того чтобы раз в день обновлять курс валют, но я не понимаю как именно мне вызывать эту команду? Возможно есть другие идеи что нужно написать в task?

Comment: Можно было бы не мудрить и просто взять cron, но раз уж взяли celery, то https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: Если проблема в том, как вызвать команду, то можно использовать `call_command`: `from django.core.management import call_command; call_command('updatecurrencies')`